# Blender Object doesnt follow my bones again :(

Tags: rigging

This time I tried to join all created objects..

(A problem with join  is always that I cant modify the objects after this.
Its all glued up. someone has any idea why this is good?)

But ok... I joined everything and then I added a skeleton with bones..
**But incredibly the eyes and the trowser doesn't follow -.-**

I put the model into the attachment...
(Per accident I put to much subdivision modifier than needed.)

patrick star blender model:
https://pasteall.org/blend/4a6521779dbc4e51bf4e5515bc197a36

or just paste a video... it cant be that hard right?

**lol I think your description was good!**

- first parent the trouser with the bones.
- then parent the body with the bones
- then join body and trouser

Thats really complicated xD
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the trousers: For some reason it's better to parent it independently then join it again, so go in *Edit* mode, select it with <kbd>L</kbd> and separate it as a new object with <kbd>P</kbd>, parent the body *With Automatic Weights*, parent the trousers *With Automatic Weights*, join the trousers back to the body with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

For the eyes, select them in *Edit* mode, go into the *Object Data* panel > *Vertex Groups*, click on the down arrow button on the right of the vertex groups list and choose *Remove from All Groups*, then select the vertex group to which they should be part of (which is the head bone called *Bone*) and click on the *Assign* button:

[image]

Comment: nice! I will try it out as soon as  I sweeped the yard here xD

Comment: Assigning the eyes  worked good it think. L also really separetes the trouser.  But then  I get confused..Parent  the body and  then the trouser?

Comment: Ah now I think I got it. Why is this so confusing and not intuitiv? Is it done normally different? This cant be the normal way xD

Comment: parenting With Automatic Weights works better if the cloth is a separate object, then join it to the rest. I can't tell why the calculation is not good with a single object

Comment: I have a additional question. Can I look for a predefined animation @ maximo and pass the movement to patricks bones? Or Should I put new bones (maximo) with already "programmed" movement  tp patrick ... for example. I want that patrick walks .. I could animate it now by myself... but it would be nice to take a already sample from maximo or something

Comment: you can give an existing action to an another armature, you just need to make sure that your armature has the same bone names, otherwise the action can't act on the bones. You can also give an existing armature to your character, and in Edit mode you can adjuct the bones to the length of your character

Comment: ok thank you!  I will do something like that :D